# Vb.net equivalent query for c# linq query

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

Can any one provide the vb.net equivalent query for the below C# linq query

```
var res= from volunteer in dtavailableVolunteers 
    group volunteer by volunteer.Id into g
    let volunteerDates = g.Select(groupedElement=>groupedElement.date)
    where arr.All(date=>volunteerDates.Contains(date))
    select g.Key
```

I wrote the below query but it is throwing 'overload resolution failed because no accessible 'select' can be called with these arguments' Exception

```
 Dim dr As DataRow() = From item In dtavailableVolunteers.AsEnumerable() _ 
 Group item By item.VolunteerId Into g = Group
                          Let volunteerDates = g.[Select](Function(groupedElement) groupedElement.Field("SelectedDate")) _
                          Where SelectedDatesArray.All(Function([SelectedDate]) volunteerDates.Contains([SelectedDate])) Select g
```

Comment: If dtavailableVolunteers is an (untyped) DataTable, your C# code won't work either. For example, DataRows don't have an `Id` property.

Answer (score 0):

I just converted it from an [online conversion tool](http://converter.telerik.com/).. I dont know if its correct. Please test if it works...

```
Dim res = _
    Let volunteerDates = g.[Select](Function(groupedElement) groupedElement.[date]) _
    Where arr.All(Function([date]) volunteerDates.Contains([date]))
```

Comment: no this is not usefull.It is throwing the same exception at select statement